# How to remove the file '--help'

Tags: bash, delete-file

Ok, I somewhat stupidly created the file '--help'.

I don't know how exactly I created the file, but it is probably something like an accidental redirection of output. :

```
cat somefile.txt > --help
```

But what I mainly noted it's harder to delete such file, than meets the eye.

```
rm --help
```

or

```
mv --help removeme.txt
rm removeme.txt
```

See --help not as a file but an option.
The only method I could figure out was something like this

```
cd somedir
rm $OLDPWD/--help
```

Or even more lame delete it with fileroller or an other filemanager.
But there must be some way to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
rm -- --help

rm ./--help
```

Answer (score 3):

That should do the trick:

```
rm -- --help
```

The `--` basically says that everyting afterwards shall not be treated as an option.